# Delete locked/open file via Graph API/SDK

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-sdks, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I'm trying to delete a file in a document library (SharePoint online) via the Graph SDK

```cs
await client
    .Drives[driveId]
    .Items[sourceItemId]
    .Request()
    .DeleteAsync();
```

This work. But if the file is open it'll throw this error:

```
Status Code: Locked
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: resourceLocked
Message: The resource you are attempting to access is locked
```

How do I force it to delete anyway?

If I try to delete the open file via the SharePoint online UI (browser) then I get a popup saying it's locked but I can choose to delete it anyway. So deleting locked/open files is possible. They just forgot to document it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: I would suggest you to file the above as an uservoice with Microsoft Graph OneDrive team. So that they can consider implementing this as a new feature. Here's the closest uservoice that i remember - https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/39962176-allow-read-write-access-to-deleted-data-in-onedriv

Comment: Being said that i remember an related SO thread in the samelines, let me share it here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61554807/microsoft-update-driveitem-api-throwing-locked-exception-if-the-file-is-open-in

Answer (score 0):

I was also using graph SDK to perform the same action, but haven't found any useful thread to remove/ignore the existing file lock. Then I found one method named `DeleteWithParameters()` under `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File` class, which accepts one parameter of type `FileDeleteParameters` through which we can set `BypassSharedLock`  parameter as true to bypass the existing lock. The code will be like the following:

```
 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileDeleteParameters fileParams = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileDeleteParameters();
 fileParams.BypassSharedLock = true;
 var testDocument = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(uri.LocalPath);
 testDocument.DeleteWithParameters(fileParams);
 clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

For your reference :

[image]

Please note: I know this is not answering the exact question, since the OP is asked for an option to remove/ignore the lock using graph SDK. But still, others can use this approach since it's a part of `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` not any external sdk.